# NodeJS download file not working on IE

Tags: node.js, express, download

I've ran into a problem that seems very simple to me, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.  I have a simple NodeJS server that uses ExpressJS that basically verifies an email and grants the user access to a zip file.  The problem is this works great on Chrome and Firefox but not on IE until I open the F12 developer console.  I've looked through all documentation I came across on here and various other sites with no mentions of similar problems.

My guess is some setting isn't enabled on IE, but I've verified I have active scripting enabled, and lowered my security level.  This problem is happening for all my IE users and I'm hoping someone will have an answer for me.

```
var stat = fs.statSync('myFile.zip');
res.writeHead(200, {
'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 
      'Content-Length': stat.size,
      'Content-disposition' : 'attachment; filename="myFile.zip'
});
console.log('Starting download: ' + 'myFile.zip' );
var stream = fs.createReadStream( 'myFile.zip', { bufferSize: 64 * 1024 });
stream.pipe(res);

//res.download( 'myFile.zip', "myFile.zip" );
```

As you can see I've tried both ExpressJS's `res.download` and `stream.pipe` with the exact same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a double quote, does adding it help?

```
'Content-disposition' : 'attachment; filename="myFile.zip"'
```

If that doesn't work, maybe try :

```
res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Length': stat.size,
});
res.attachment('myFile.zip');
```

Comment: Great catch on the missing quote, that unfortunately doesn't fix it though.  I also did a few tests with your suggested way to download the file and I still get the same result, where I don't get a download to start until I hit F12.

Comment: I ended up finding out the problem, it actually was on the client side, apparently console.log doesn't play well with IE.